# Writing in a <div> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**What I am trying to get is:**
Make a `<div>` which shows a "You have selected seat 1." message, when I clicked the associated button inside the `<div>`. Additionaly it should be possible to click multiple buttons which should result in a proper displayed "You have selected 1,... and x." message.

**Question**
How can I archieve this?

**Side information**
I need this for a lot of buttons because it's a cinema reservation system.

**What I have so far**

```
   <script>
       function text(id){
           document.getElementById("bookingDiv").innerHTML = "seat 1";
       }
   </script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
    <input class="textbutton" type="button" id="Button1" value="seat1"
           onclick="text(Button1)"/>
    <input class="textButton"type="button" id="Button2" value="seat2"
           onclick="text(Button2)"/>

    <div id="bookingDiv" type="text">
        you have selected button:
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("#bookingDiv").innerHTML = "seat 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input class="textbutton" type="button" id="Button1" value="seat1" />
<input class="textbutton"type="button" id="Button2" value="seat2" />
<div id="bookingDiv" type="text">
you have selected button:
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.textbutton').on("click",function(){
        $('#bookingDiv').html( $('#bookingDiv').html() + ';' + $(this).attr('value') );
    });
});
```

**Add following JavaScript Reference**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" />
```

Comment: This will keep adding "Button1" and "Button2" to the div, even if you keep clicking it.

Comment: @Stan this is just an idea on how to append. The OP should change it accordingly.

Comment: His question wasn't how to append a string to another string, though.  If you're trying to nudge the OP in the right direction, but you don't want to answer his entire question, try leaving a comment, instead!

Answer (score 0):

To set the text of a div, use its innerhtml property:

```
$("#bookingDiv").innerhtml("you have selected blah blah blah");
```

Edit:

You should change your seat buttons to checkboxes.  Then you can just see if they're checked:

```
if ($("#chkSeat1").prop("checked"))
```

Try this:  Add a class called 'SeatButtons' to all your seat checkboxes (change them from buttons to checkboxes).  Give them IDs of 'chkSeat1', 'chkSeat2', etc.  Then, any time a 'SeatButtons' checkbox is clicked, you can iterate through all of them to see if they're checked, like so:

```
$(".SeatButtons").click(function(){
var SeatList = "";
var PickedASeatAlready = false;
$("#.SeatButtons").each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked")){
       if (PickedASeatAlready )
            SeatList += ", ";
       SeatList += $(this).prop("id").replace("chkSeat", "");
       PickedASeatAlready = true;
    }
});
if (PickedASeatAlready )
   $("#bookingDiv").innerthtml = "You have selected seats " + SeatList;
else
    $("bookingDiv").innerhtml = "You have not yet selected any seats";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

SEE this live example

http://fiddle.jshell.net/a53pfLja/

```
function text(data){

document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = data;

}


</script>




<body>



<input class="textbutton" type="button" id="Button1" value="seat1" onclick="text('Button1')"/>
<input class="textButton"type="button" id="Button2" value="seat2" onclick="text('Button2')"/>
<div id="bookingDiv">
    <span>
        you have selected button:
    </span>
    <span id="button">
    </span>
</div>


</body>
```